# Product of logarithms, prove this identity.

Tags: logarithms

Is it hard to prove this identity:
$$2 \log (a) \log (b)=\log(a b)^2-\log(a)^2-\log(b)^2$$

for $a>1$ and $b>1$?

Comment: Use $$\log a^m=m\log a$$ to (dis)prove

Comment: Judging by Yiyuan Lee and Umberto P.'s answer,the correct answer should be "no".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

$$\begin{align}(\log ab)^2 &= (\log a + \log b)^2 \\
&= (\log a)^2 + (\log b)^2 + 2\log a \log b \end{align}$$

Now, just rearrange by leaving $2\log a \log b$ on the right hand side.

Answer (score 15):

Here's a hint: $A^2 + 2AB +B^2 = (A+B)^2$. Here's another hint: $\log a + \log b = \log(ab)$.